# Followed Spring MVC Guide, But Template Literal Values Won't Display Correctly?

Tags: java, spring

So I was following a guide on how to create a Spring MVC, but an issue I'm running into is that it seems to not display the template literal values correctly.

Here's the guide and the code:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ArHUCL_RRc

https://github.com/RameshMF/spring-mvc-tutorial/tree/master/springmvc5-helloworld-exmaple

Essentially, I'm following it one to one, creating a model, controller, and config that should display the message and the current date and time. However, it does not display template literals correctly, showing them as literally ${helloWorld.message}. I'm not sure if it's an issue of the helloWorld not being created, or of it's something else. Any tips?

helloworld.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring 5 MVC - Hello World Example | javaguides.net</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>${helloWorld.message}</h2>
    <h4>Server date time is : ${helloWorld.dateTime}</h4>
</body>
</html>
```

HelloWorldController.java

```
package net.te549.springmvc.controller;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;

import net.te549.springmvc.model.HelloWorld;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {
    @RequestMapping("/helloworld")
    public String handler(Model model) {
        
        HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
        helloWorld.setMessage("Hello World from TE549!!!");
        helloWorld.setDateTime(LocalDateTime.now().toString());
        model.addAttribute("helloWorld", helloWorld);
        return "helloworld";
    }
}
```

HelloWorld.java

```
package net.te549.springmvc.model;

public class HelloWorld {
    private String message;
    private String dateTime;
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message=message;
    }
    public String getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }
    public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
        this.dateTime=dateTime;
    }
}
```

(If I need to show more code, let me know)

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was wrong. (I was too quick...). I don't know much about JSP - maybe the returned string needs to be `helloWorld` instead of `helloworld`? (uppder case *W*)

Comment: That doesn't quite work, since editing HelloWorldController.java's `return "helloWorld"` returns an error of being unable to find "helloWorld.jsp".

Answer (score 1):

Kindly Check if there is any errors/exception in logs if not Try Adding this in your JSP:

```
<%@page isELIgnored="false"%>
```